# Tkinter не выводит виджеты

Tags: python, tkinter

Я пытаюсь сделать нечто похожее на блокнот. Код ниже выводит только окно Tkinter, но ни поля text, ни кнопки нет. Пробовала его в PyCharm и Visual stuio code. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

```
from tkinter import *

def give():
    a = open("blocknot.txt", "w+")
    v = text_box.get("1.0", END)
    a.write(v)
    a.close()

root = Tk()
root.geometry('500x500')
root.title('Blocknot')

global entry
text_box = Text(width = 50,
                height = 90)

text_box.pack

Button(text = 'Save',
       width = 3,
       height = 5,
       command = give()).pack

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pack` - это метод, его нужно вызвать, поставив круглые скобки:

```py
text_box.pack()
#            ^^ - скобки для вызова
```

и

```py
Button(text = 'Save',
       width = 3,
       height = 5,
       command = give()).pack()
#                            ^^ - здесь тоже
```